# Does AsyncTaskLoader really inherit from AsyncTaskLoader?

Tags: java, inheritance, android-asynctask, android-studio, asynctaskloader

If you highlight a class in Drodio (Android Studio) and mash Ctrl+N, it will show you the inheritance hierarchy for that class, like so for AsyncTask:

[image]

This seems to indicate that AsyncTaskLoader inherits from AsyncTaskLoader? Is that so? If so, was that intentional? Or what is going on here?

### UPDATE

My bad; I read "Ctrl+N" in the tip where it really says, "Ctrl+H". Here's what you get with the latter:

[image]

(though still not just what I expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this accurately would require knowing more about your project (presumably hhs.app). However, Drodio's hierarchy did discover `PersistHistoryAsyncTask`, which is a private inner class of `ActivityChooserModel`, not listed in the Android documentation due to being a private class, so my point on *no* classes in that android library inheriting from `AsyncTask` in my original response (below) was incorrect.

Assuming the listed inner classes in `RESTfulActivity`, `SQLiteActivity`, `MainActivity`, and `DeliveryItemActivity` all extend `AsyncTask`, the results in your second screenshot are entirely expected. `AsyncTask` does not inherit from anything (except `Object`, obviously), and you have 9 classes extending `AsyncTask`. So, you have the very simple hierarchy:

```
java.lang.Object
  |
  +-- android.os.AsyncTask
        |
        +-- hhs.app.RESTfulActivity.PostDeliveryItemTask
        |
        +-- hhs.app.SQLiteActivity.FetchAndPopTask
        |
        +-- hhs.app.MainActivity.GetVendorsTask
        |
        +-- hhs.app.DeliveryItemActivity.PostDeliveryItemTask
        |
        +-- etc...
```

---

#### Original Answer:

You're looking at two different classes: `android.content.AsyncTaskLoader` and `android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader`.

The former is an:

> Abstract Loader that provides an `AsyncTask` to do the work.

The latter is a:

> Static library support version of the framework's `AsyncTaskLoader`. Used to write apps that run on platforms prior to Android 3.0.

Both `AsyncTaskLoader` classes inherit from a class named `Loader` in their same package, and the two `Loader` classes inherit from `Object`. None of the classes in question implement any interfaces.

You can see the source for both classes on grepcode.com:

- [android.content.AsyncTaskLoader](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.java)
- [android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/content/AsyncTaskLoader.java)

Neither class is coupled to the other in any way that I can see. The support version imports `android.content.Context`, but `Context` doesn't do anything with the `AsyncTaskLoader` in its own package.

All that said, it does not appear that the feature of Drodio you've posted a screenshot of is intended to be the inheritance tree at all. Rather, it's a class search. You've highlighted `AsyncTask`, and the search results show 3 other classes which begin with "AsyncTask", 2 classes which end with "AsyncTask", and 1 which begins with "Async" and ends with "Task" (all that in addition to the actual `AsyncTask` class). Considering `AsyncTask` does not inherit from *any* of these classes (`AsyncTask` doesn't extend or implement anything) nor do any of these classes inherit from `AsyncTask` (in `android.*` there are no classes which extend `AsyncTask`), it seems evident that this feature of Drodio has nothing to do with inheritance.

The fact that Driodo is not displaying your own concrete implementation of `AsyncTask` seems to be the final nail in the coffin, particular since your cursor is on the very line that defines the subclass. (While not all IDEs can incorporate user-defined functions into documentation pop-ups, most will at *least* be able to handle things in the same file.)

Comment: You're right - I misread "Ctrl+H" for "Ctrl+N" in the tip. Updated with a screen shot.